# How do I convert this "developer commentary" to an image?

Tags: portal-2

In the following video, a hidden commentary is discovered, they think that it's an image in audio form...

How can it be turned into an image?

Comment: Hm. It looks like the ARG Wiki guys haven't touched this yet.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Wrong (see answer)

Comment: @Nick - ah. I was going off of the info on the main page, which says "The sound heard when completing the "Final Transmission" achievement has been decoded (by Seikas) and shown to produce this image. Unsure if this is the same exact transmission played with listening to this commentary node in Chapter 3, test chamber 17 (above the chamber in one of Rattmann's hidden rooms)."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an [SSTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-scan_television) signal, which turns into the following images when decoded.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Decoded courtesy [the ARG folks over at valvearg.info](http://valvearg.com/wiki/Com-arg.wav)

Comment: Ah, apparently it looks like a computer, a mouse and a screen...